# Black Jack with Classes

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a black jack game that uses classes in order to run. I believe I have successfully made a class that is for the card

```
class Card(object):
    def __init__(self,suit,number):
        self.suit=suit
        self.number=number
```

I then made a class that takes a deck and then shuffles it and it deals is as well, I think that this class is also correct (I am slightly unsure about the deal function)

```
class DeckofCards(object):
    def __init__(self,deck):
        self.deck=deck
        self.shuffledeck=self.shuffle()
        print(self.shuffledeck)
    def shuffle(self):
        b=[]
        count=0
        while count<len(self.deck):
            a=randrange(0,len(self.deck))
            if a not in b:
                b.append(self.deck[a])
                count+=1
        return(b)
    def deal(self):
        if len(self.shuffledeck)>0:
            return(self.shuffledeck.pop(0)) #removes the card from the deck and deals it
        else:
            shuffle(self)
            return(self.shuffledeck.pop(0))
```

I then created a class for the player and this is where things start to confuse me, I hope it is OK to insert the direct question from the teacher because it is very ambiguous and confusing to me.

> class Player(object):
>
> “”” This class is for the players in the game (a
>   dealer is considered a player, although I  could have made a separate
>   class for the dealer.) The constructor has 6 properties:  the player’s
>   name, the hand (initially an empty list), the boolean value inout,
>   which  is initialized to True (for indicating that the player is
>   “in”), the Boolean value  blackjack, which is initialized to False
>   (indicating the player does not have  blackjack), the integer money,
>   indicating the total amount of money the player has,  score,
>   initialized to 0,and the integer bid, initialized to 0, which will
>   hold the  player’s current bid.

This was my attempt

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self,name,hand,inout,money,score):
        self.name=name
        self.hand=hand
        self.inout=inout
        self.money=money
        self.score=score
        self.blackjack=self.blackjacksearch()
    def blackjacksearch(self): #not sure if any of this works
        if Card('H','J') in self.hand:
            return(False)
        if Card('S','J') in self.hand:
            return(False)
        if Card('C','J') in self.hand:
            return(False)
        if Card('D','J') in self.hand:
            return(False)
        else:
            return(True)
```

The complete directions can be found [here](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~yarringt/106/LabsSpring13/Project2BlackJack.pdf)

I am just looking for some direction, because I am clueless and our professor hasn't been very helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming players always start with an empty list for their hand, then you don't have to do the blackjack search yet as they will always have no blackjack (False), they will always be 'in' (True), they will have 0 score and 0 bid.

Just because your professor says 'the constructor has six properties' doesn't mean 'the constructor must take six parameters' - in Python, since there's no such thing as declaring what variables a class must have, it makes sense to set them up in the constructor, even if it will only ever be to default values. I would pass in only name to the constructor and the rest of the properties of Player would be alterable by methods (that are only allowed to move it from one valid state to another and handle all side effects, of course)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a reference implementation of black jack in java , it may help you model your classes. https://github.com/alkber/blackjack